# I filed a FICA return and sent it to the IRS, but my company sent me a W2C and also refunded the money. What should I do?

Tags: income-tax, income-tax-refund, amended-tax-return

I am an F1 student <5 years in the USA and am eligible for FICA refunds.

I contacted my company and told them that I will be requesting the IRS for the FICA refund as I was very close to the last date for filing tax returns and there wasn't enough time. They accepted and I sent my returns to IRS. However, 6 weeks later, I received a check from my company with the refund amount and the corrected W2c document, even though I had asked them not to. 
Now that I have obtained the refund from the company, what should I do? Do I need to send an amendment to the IRS? 
Note- IRS has NOT sent me a FICA refund yet.

Comment: "*Do I need to send an amendment to the IRS?*" Probably. But I'd wait for the IRS check, or some other communication from them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Any idea about how long they usually take to communicate? Tried calling the IRS but didn't get through!

Comment: Eight weeks *should* be long enough.

Comment: Thank you! I'll report back if I get anything.